# log linearize exponential expressions

Tags: log-linearization

How do I log-linearize an expression like:

$e^{(\theta*(x_t-\bar{x}))}$

Where $\theta$ is any constant and $\bar{x}$ is the steady-state of $x$

Generally when we log-linearize say $x_t$, we write it as

$x_t = \bar{x} * e^{(log(X_t-log(\bar{x}))}
     = 1 + X_t$

where $x_t = log(x_t-log(\bar{x}))$

But in my current problem, the expression itself is exponential. So is the following right?

exp(theta*(X(t)-X_bar)) = exp(exp(theta*(log(X(t)-log(X_bar))) * exp(exp(-theta*(log(X_bar)-log(X_bar))))

which boils down to exp(exp(theta*x(t))) * exp(1) = exp(1 + exp(theta*x(t)))
= 1 + 1 + exp(theta*x(t))

Answer (score 1):

The aim of log-linearization is to get an expression that is linear in the deviation from steady state $x_t$, where $x_t:=\log(X_t/X)$, $X$ is the steady state of $X_t$ and we have $X_t = Xe^{x_t} \approx X(1+x_t)$.

The **general approach of log-linearization is** (1) to take logs of both sides of the equation and then (2) do a Taylor series expansion of these log-functions (one on each side of the equation).

But in many cases, just plugging $X(1+x_t)$ for $X_t$ into the expression gives you something that is linear in $x_t$ right away, but not for exponential expressions such as in your example, as you tried to do. This is easy to see:

$$
e^{\theta(X_t-X)} \approx e^{\theta((X(1+x_t)-X)} = e^{\theta Xx_t}
$$
is clearly not linear in $x_t$, so that approach won't work. However, if $\theta X x_t
$ is "small", you can use $e^{\theta X x_t}\approx 1 + \theta X x_t$ and you are done.

Generally, if one runs into expressions as above, or the result is non-linear otherwise, the general approach needs to be used. This is also what's applied in DSGE models such cases.

**General approach:**

Take logs, then do a Taylor series expansion. Define $f(X_t)=\theta(X_t-X)$.
$$
\log\bigl(e^{\theta(X_t-X)}\bigr)=\theta(X_t-X)\approx f(0) + f'(0)(X_t-X)= 0 + \theta(X_t-X) \approx \theta X x_t
$$

Here, $\theta X x_t$ is the log-linearization of $e^{\theta(X_t-X)}$. If $\theta X x_t$ is "small", you can recover the level version by simply applying the exponential, which gives you
$$
e^{\theta(X_t-X)} \approx 1 + \theta X x_t
$$
The general approach gives an expression that is linear in $x_t$. Note that you can take a higher order Taylor series, which will also be linear in $x_t$, to get a better approximation and capture more of the dynamics, which is sometimes used if the expression is highly non-linear.

Comment: No I donr think this is completely right. I am sure the expression exp(theta*X) will not exists because we will substitute X(t)=X in steady state which implies exp(theta*(X-X))=exp(0)=1

Comment: Indeed I should have mentioned the case where $X_t=X$.  Added this, and a more general solution to my answer.

Comment: What you are doing is linearisation. Approximating exp(theta*X) around steady state X_bar is well documented in basic textbooks. What I am asking is log linearisation of exponential functions. The answer to that starts from what I have explained. I am reaching some complex expressions and thats why I wanted to make sure from people working with advanced economics. Generally people who do DSGE models can confirm this. If there are people in this forum that have encountered log-linearisation of exponential terms while doing DSGE models may please take a look at my problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer further to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, this should work.

Comment: @Sanaya, can you then please accept.